# Is there a more formal way to say, "As an added bonus"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

"As an added bonus" seems quite casual. Is there a word or phrase that expresses it that is suitable in a 'serious' essay? For example, "... Thus, equations give us scientific knowledge. As an added bonus, equations are easier to use than their alternatives."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"As an additional benefit"*** should work in most contexts. It just substitutes *"additional"* for the possibly-less-formal *"added"*, and *"benefit"* for the definitely-less-formal *"bonus"*. You can also go in-between in formality by using ***"as an added benefit"***.

Comment: As an added benefit is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Or simply, "In addition, equations are ..." etc.

Comment: @Jay, that doesn't get across the fact that the additional listed features are a good thing.

Comment: @Martha Sure. Depending on context, it may be obvious that the additional things are good and maybe not. Or you may want to emphasize that they are good. I was just mentioning alternatives, not saying that there was anything wrong with your post.

Answer (score 2):

**as a bonus** would suffice. Bonus already means 'something extra', and is derived from the Latin bonus ('good').

**as an added bonus** is informal [since it has a redundancy](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/16/added-bonus/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the word 'additionally' comes close to the meaning you're looking for, however it does not have quite the same positive connotations as 'as an added bonus', but in the example you give it would fit well as a replacement.